# Highcharts change or add color for name in a array of point.names and y

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors, prototype, series

I need to set the color for a array of point.name and y individually.

What i have so far:

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'getColor', function(proceed) {
    this.color = generateColorForString(this.name);
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

This is working for the following data-structure:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      [
        "2018",
        "02",
        "16",
        "00",
        "00"
      ],
      4.9
    ],
    ...
 ],
  "name": "MySeriesName"
}
```

but not for this data structure for a pie chart:

```
{
  "type": "pie",
  "name": "MySeriesName",
  "data": [
    [
      "foo",
      27
    ],
    [
      "foox",
      112
    ],
    [
      "fooy",
      4
    ]
    ...
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to set a color for every point by name?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nd8561k/2/

Comment: Hi @metamagikum, Which series type do you use? Do you want to generate some color for every point based on the point name?

Comment: Thanks. The first structure has a accessible name. Working with most data types. I want to access the name and set a color to a array point / y data series. Just added a JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `resolveColor` method from `Highcharts.Point.prototype`:

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'resolveColor', function(proceed) {
        this.color = generateColorForString(this.name);
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y4ro69dq/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect. I love SO for people like you :)  Do you know how i am able to wrap Point and Series so every chart type would be processed?

Comment: Point matches even series. Thanks again.